# How do I avoid entering a value twice

Tags: c++, function, c++11, for-loop

Description:Suppose we can buy a chocolate bar from the vending machine for $1 each. Inside every chocolate
bar is a coupon. We can redeem six coupons for one chocolate bar from the machine. This means
that once you have started buying chocolate bars from the machine, you always have some coupons.

Write a program to know how many chocolate bars can be eaten if we start with N dollars and always
redeem coupons if we have enough for an additional chocolate bar.

I am required to write two functions and use for loop.

I do not want to enter the dollar value twice.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int chocCalc(int n){

    int choc = 0, coup = 0, moreChoc = 0, dollars;

    cout << "Enter dollars: ";
    cin >> dollars;

// Calculating for amount of chocolates including the ones reedemed by cupons.


    int i=0;
    for (i = 1; i <= dollars; i++  ){
    choc = dollars;
    coup = choc;
    moreChoc = coup / 6;
    choc += moreChoc;

    return choc;
    }

}

int cupon(int m){

    int choc = 0, coup = 0, moreChoc = 0, dollars, coupLeft = 0;

    cout << "Enter dollars again: ";
    cin >> dollars;


    int i=0;
    for (i = 1; i <= dollars; i++  ){
    choc = dollars;
    coup = choc;

// calculating the amount of cupons left


    moreChoc = coup / 6;
    choc += moreChoc;
    coupLeft = coup%6;

    return coupLeft;
    }

}
int main(){

    cout << "You can eat: " << chocCalc(0) << " chocolates \n";
    cout << "and " << cupon(0) << " cupons are left.";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Set dollars as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

No global variables

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int enterDollars(){
     int dollars;
     cout<<"Enter Dollars:";
     cin>>dollars;
     return dollars;
}
int chocCalc(int dollars){

    int choc = 0, coup = 0, moreChoc = 0;


// Calculating for amount of chocolates including the ones reedemed by cupons.


    int i=0;
    for (i = 1; i <= dollars; i++  ){
    choc = dollars;
    coup = choc;
    moreChoc = coup / 6;
    choc += moreChoc;

    return choc;
    }

}

int cupon(int dollars){

    int choc = 0, coup = 0, moreChoc = 0, coupLeft = 0;




    int i=0;
    for (i = 1; i <= dollars; i++  ){
    choc = dollars;
    coup = choc;

// calculating the amount of cupons left


    moreChoc = coup / 6;
    choc += moreChoc;
    coupLeft = coup%6;

    return coupLeft;
    }

}
int main(){
    int dollars = enterDollars();
    cout << "You can eat: " << chocCalc(dollars) << " chocolates \n";
    cout << "and " << cupon(dollars) << " cupons are left.";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I said in in the end an alternative to not use global variables

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the alternative. Perhaps you could share a code sample.